# Join table on itself

Tags: mysql, join

I have sufficiently hurt my brain now trying to figure out the logic behind this.

I have a table as follows

```
entry_id | cat_id
       1 | 233
       1 | 234
       1 | 678
       2 | 235
       2 | 453
       2 | 21
       3 | 234
       3 | 123
```

Is there a way to return in a single query, every category id that is also associated with the same entry ids.  So, the select statement would select based on the cat_id, for example 234.  What would be returned are the category IDs:
233, 678, 123

Comment: do you mean 233, 234 and 678?

Comment: @climbage: No, 233, 678, and 123 seems right.  Unless he also wants the id he was searching for (234).

Comment: Ah I missed that 234 was also part of entry 3, that's why I was confused.  Carry on

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
SELECT  t2.cat_id
FROM    mytable t1
JOIN    mytable t2
ON      t2.entry_id = t1.entry_id
        AND t2.cat_id <> t1.cat_id
WHERE   t1.cat_id = 234
```

Comment: Seeing what OP wants, that should be `SELECT DISTINCT t2.cat_id`, shouldn't it?

Comment: @ypercube: it may or may not be so, we don't know exactly. Probably he would want to count the matches on categories, or something else.

Comment: You nailed it, while Eugene was a little before you in terms of quickness, this query works against my database much more speedily.  I don't know the etiquette of marking answers correct, so if I should have marked you as correct answer Eugene, I apologize :P

Comment: @macgyver: since both give correct result, you can upvote both.

Answer (score 5):

```
SELECT cat_id FROM table
  WHERE entry_id IN (SELECT entry_id FROM table WHERE cat_id = 234)
AND cat_id <> 234
```

Comment: This query will fail on the data provided by the @op.

Comment: @Quassnoi: Why will this fail?

Comment: because he used '=' instead of in. Equal refers to only one value.

Comment: @Rocket: because the subquery will return more than one row.

Comment: @Nikki9696: yes it will, and for that very reason.

Comment: @Quassnoi: Yeah, you're right.  How did I not notice that?  Need... more... coffee...

Comment: From his example, I gathered that was what he wanted. His answers included all the numbers. "What would be returned are the category IDs: 233, 678, 123" Those are entries 1 and 3, which are also associated with 234. Am I missing something? (he edited it to IN; I read it as IN, was that it? I also need coffee)

Comment: You should also have `AND t2.cat_id <> 234` to exclude 234, don't you?

Answer (score 1):

```
select t1.* 
from yourtable t1
join yourtable t2 on (t1.entry_id=t2.entry_id and t1.cat_id<>t2.cat_id)
where t2.cat_id=[your cat]
```